# Set Center position for a div element that has display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

I know when we set margin left and right to auto value for an html block element that has a specified width, then the element has center position.
But if I want to wrapper to have auto size depend on content, I set `display : inline-block`, but now center position is not working.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're setting display: inline-block to an element you can have a wrapper to that element with:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sGaTZ/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a wrapper, you can try this:

```
<div class="box">test</div>
```

and the **CSS**:

```
.box {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Using `display: table` with no specific width will cause the box to shrink-to-fit the content.  You can then center it using `margin: 0 auto`.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/FdnGs/